# Smallest supremum norm of a set

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $K \subset D(0;r)$ be connected, compact and ${\rm diam} K \ge r$. Let $S=\mathbb{C}-K$ be connected. It is known that $S$ is simply connected and then there exists a conformal mapping $f:D(0;1) \to S$ such that $f(0)=\infty$. Then we have
\begin{equation}
f(w)=\frac{A}{w}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nw^n.
\end{equation} If we define $F=\frac{1}{A}f^{-1}$, then $F$ is a conformal mapping of $S$ onto the disk $D(0;|a|^{-1})$. Clearly, $zF(z)=a^{-1}wf(w)$ which implies $zF(z) \to 1$ as $z \to \infty$. Is it true that this $F$ satisfies $\|F\|_\infty \le \|g\|_\infty$ for all $g \in H(S)$ such that $zg(z) \to 1$ as $z \to \infty$? So far I can't find a counter-example, so I guess this statement is right, but how does one prove it? Please comment on it. Thanks!

Comment: wlog one can assume $A>0$ and then this is a straightforward application of Schwarz Lemma; assume there is a (clearly nonconstant) $g$ as above with $A^{-1}=\|F\|_\infty \ge \|g\|_\infty$ or equivalently $g(S) \subset D(0;A^{-1})$; then show that $h(w)=g(f(w/A))$ self-maps the disc $D(0;A^{-1})$ (sending zero to zero) with derivative at zero $1/A$ hence it is a rotation so $\|g\|_\infty=A^{-1}=\|F\|_\infty$

Comment: Got it! Nice solution. Thanks again!